# Logging in with Parse and FB using a different account

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm implementing the Parse / Facebook login for iOS and it's working well - I'm logged in with my own FB user and everything is fine.

But now I want to log in to my iOS application from a different FB user - a tester's account. This is what I did:

1. Went to my FB application on my iPhone, logged out, and logged in again with my Test account.
2. Went back to my iOS / Parse application and attempted to Login With Facebook.
   The result is that I'm logged in with my own account!

I uninstalled the app, and re-run it from xCode, logged in with Facebook - and I'm back in using my own account again.

No matter what I do, I keep going back to my own account. It looks like Parse, or FB, is cacheing my info somehow. How do I un-cache it to get a fresh start?

This is my login method:

```
- (void)loginWithFB  {
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    // Login PFUser using facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error" message:@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
        [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MyTrack alloc] init] animated:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");

        FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSString *facebookUsername = [result objectForKey:@"username"];
                [PFUser currentUser].username = facebookUsername;
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveEventually];
                NSLog(@"Welcome Screen I am %@", [[PFUser currentUser] username]);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error getting the FB username %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];


        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
        [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
}];

    [_activityIndicator startAnimating]; // Show loading indicator until login is finished

}
```

Comment: Are you ever calling `logOut` on the current user?

Comment: Yes, I do. As a test I even tried putting the [PFUser logOut] at the start of this method but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this when you logout

```
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
FBSession.activeSession = nil;
```

Comment: I did. Now when I'm logging in again I get this: FBSDKLog: -1059155737 is not a valid FBSessionLoginBehavior. Ignoring open call. And the user is still my own, and not the tester's.